# How to know which item python chooses with random.choice?

Tags: python, random

I'd like to know which item python chooses with `random.choice` so I can use `if` statements for different outcomes.

```
thelists = [L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6]
theplayers = random.choice(thelists)
```

I'd like to know which list, L1, L2..., the variable `theplayers` will refer to.

Comment: alternatively, `index, lst = random.choice(list(enumerate(thelists)))` or use a hash instead of a list and do `list_name, lst = random.choice(thehashoflists.items())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html#random.choice):

> `random.choice(seq)`
>
> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence
> `seq`. If `seq` is empty, raises `IndexError`.

Here, `seq` is your list.

You can get the index of the selected element with:

```
thelists.index(theplayers)
```

Comment: `.index()` won't necessarily work.  If there are two equal lists, `.index()` will only tell you where the first one is.

Comment: There wont be lists that are the same for this^ so  this will work fine :p

Comment: Besides what @DSM said, it's also much simpler (and more efficient) to keep the index around, instead of throwing away and searching for it again, as mentioned under all the other answers. This really shouldn't be the answer you accept (and implement).

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [`random.randint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) instead, so you don't have to use `list.index` to find the list later:

```
from random import randint

# your list of lists
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
# choose a valid *index* into l, at random
index = randint(0,len(l) - 1)
# use the randomly chosen index to get a reference to the list
choice = l[index]

# write your conditionals which handle different choices
if index == 1:
    print 'first list'
elif index == 2:
    print 'second list'
...
```

This will be more efficient than using `random.choice` and then `list.index` each time you make a choice.

Comment: This or `random.choice(enumerate(thelists))` seems like the most sensible choice.

Comment: @hayden: have to be `list(enumerate(thelists))`, I think -- `random.choice` needs to know the length.

Comment: @DSM Good point, difficult to choose uniformly from a possibly infinite generator!

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple:

```
 res = random.choice(my_list)
```

Comment: @user1807371: The "res"/"theplayers" will hold the chosen list. Are you stuck on something else?